# How to work with Jenkins Slaves

Tags: svn, jenkins

Forgive my ignorance I am very new to jenkins and need to understand how I configure slaves.

I have a My Jenkins master running on my internal network Windows Server and have setup and installed a slave node on a server on a different network.

On my master I have jobs that does and SVN update and runs some local batch jobs afterwards.    I want to do the same thing on my slave,  Ive read the documentention but its not clear how I setup a job to run on the slave.   can someone help me out here.   detailed step by step instructions with information for any plugins  I need would be really apprecicated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the same thing to happen on the Slave instead of the Master then restrict the job to run on the Slave only.

Job-> Configure -> CheckBox - Restrict where this project can be run. 
Then put the name of the slave in the Label Expression.

Answer (score 0):

The answer I was looking for was to use Multi-configuration project and then select the slave from the Configuation Matrix.